# How do I use PHP to encode a string containing quotes to make it safe for inline 'onclick'?

Tags: javascript, php, html, onclick, htmlspecialchars

I have a variable in a database that could potentially contain single or double quotes. When I retrieve the variable from the database, it is written with PHP into an inline "onclick" hander:

```
echo '<li><a onClick="a4e.duplicate_assignment('.$this_assignment['id'].',\''.htmlspecialchars($this_assignment['title'],ENT_QUOTES).'\',\'/assignments/'.$type.'/\');" href="javascript:void(0);">';echo '<i class="fa fa-copy"></i> Duplicate assignment</a></li>';
```

This produces HTML that looks like this in the page source:

```
<li><a onClick="a4e.duplicate_assignment(92,'ELLLO - &#039;If I had a million dollars&#039;','/assignments/cloze/');" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-copy"></i> Duplicate assignment</a></li>
```

However, clicking the link produces the following error in the console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

I thought using the PHP function "htmlspecialchars" would mitigate this issue, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help greatly appreciated.

P.S. It is not possible in this case to use a Javascript "onclick" handler - it has to be inline HTML. Also, it is not possible to ban the use of quotation marks in the variable value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the function:

```
addslashes()
```

EDIT: This method will take care of the quotes in the string itself, but may not be suitable if you need to retain quotes for HTML insertion. Read the docs carefully.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Comment: Thanks, that did it.

Comment: The question said that the string might contain double quotes, `addslashes` won't prevent it from breaking the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

its because your Unicode (') is also being treated as '

use this

```
<li><a onClick="a4e.duplicate_assignment(92,'ELLLO - \'If I had a million dollars\'','/assignments/cloze');" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-copy"></i> Duplicate assignment</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `json_encode` to convert a value to a JavaScript literal (with all necessary escaping).

Use `htmlspecialchars` to convert a value (such as a JavaScript program) to something safe to place in an HTML attribute value.

```
$id = $this_assignment['id'];
$title = $this_assignment['title'];
$url = "/assignments/$type/";

$js_id = json_encode($id);
$js_title = json_encode($title);
$js_url = json_encode($url);
$js = "a4e.duplicate_assignment($js_id, $js_title, $js_url); 

$html_js = htmlspecialchars($js, ENT_QUOTES);
?>
<li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="<?php echo $html_js; ?>">
        <i class="fa fa-copy"></i>
        Duplicate assignment
    </a>
<li>
```

A better approach would be to use progressive enhancement and non-inline JS. You've ruled that out, but you should try to remove that restriction.

```
$id = $this_assignment['id'];
$title = $this_assignment['title'];
$url = "/assignments/$type/";

$html_id = htmlspecialchars($id, ENT_QUOTES);
$html_title = htmlspecialchars($title, ENT_QUOTES);
$html_url = htmlspecialchars($url, ENT_QUOTES);
?>
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo $html_url; ?>" data-title="<?php echo $html_title; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $html_id; ?>">
        <i class="fa fa-copy"></i>
        Duplicate assignment
    </a>
<li>
<!-- and later -->
<script>
    document.querySelector("a").addEventListener("click", duplicate_assignment_handler);

    function duplicate_assignment_handler(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        a4e.duplicate_assignment(this.dataset.id, this.dataset.title, this.href);
    }
</script>
</script>
```